# How do I get the gold hero shot replica in Splatoon

Tags: splatoon

I've been playing Splatoon for awhile and I saw a lot of gold weapons. I have the gold aerospray and gold Dynamo roller, but I want to know if there is a gold hero shot replica.

If so how do I get it?

My question is different from that question because this question is asking if there is a gold hero shot replica and how to get it and that question is asking how to get the gold Dynamo roller and gold aerospray

Comment: Logically, if someone is asking about all golden guns, then if there is one for your chosen item, then it should have it, no?

Comment: Hero replica weapons are not the same as the golden weapons. None of the hero replica weapons are gold, so there is no "gold hero shot replica". This is not a duplicate, but a case of confusion caused by the accepted answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 4):

There are only two gold weapons in the game:  the [Aerospray RG](http://splatoon.wikia.com/wiki/Aerospray_RG) and the [Gold Dynamo Roller](http://splatoon.wikia.com/wiki/Gold_Dynamo_Roller).  These are just alternate versions of these weapons and have a different set of sub weapons and specials but no special characteristics.

The [Hero Shot Replica](http://splatoon.wikia.com/wiki/Hero_Shot_Replica) can only be gotten from beating the Inkling Squid Amiibo Challenges and has no "gold version."  The same is true for every other weapon in the game (aside from the Aerospray MG and Dynamo Roller).